# CSS: How to create special shape

Tags: css

[image]

I would like to create a div as shown above.
I tried to reach my goal like this, but I do not know how to lift the border bottom.

```css
#myForm {
  border-bottom: 100px solid green;
  border-right: 70px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myForm"></div>
```

Comment: Why not use an image?

Comment: You might want to change your wording from "form" to "shape", since you're not actually using an HTML form and it's a little confusing. Potentially a translation issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements:

```css
html{
  background-color: #fff;
}

div{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

div::before, div::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
}

div::before{
  bottom: 0;
  border-width: 0 0 50px 300px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
}

div::after{
  right: 0;
  border-width: 0 20px 100px 0;
  border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/po0x30x9/1)

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! The border are not linear. There is way to fix them?

Comment: What do you mean by linear border?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to explore pseudo elements like `:before` & `:after`
The code snippet below will give you an idea of where to start, but you'll most likely need to fin tune it to suit your specific case.

```css
#myForm {
  border-bottom: 100px solid green;
  border-right: 70px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 150px;
}
div#myForm:after {
  content: "";
  border-left: 222px solid green;
  border-bottom: 27px solid transparent;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  bottom: -127px;
  z-index: 9999999;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="myForm"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use margin-bottom: -100px; as example and use !important if needed

Comment: Why? How does it help? Care for a snippet?